# Do I have the wrong interpretation of the limit inferior in this definition?

Tags: limsup-and-liminf, semicontinuous-functions

I am trying to understand the definition of lower semi-continuity. A function $f$ is lower semi-continuous at some point $x_0$ if the following holds

$$\lim_{x \to x_0} \inf f(x) \geq f(x_0).$$

This would be an example of a lower semi-continuous function: [Lower semi-continuous function](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b0/Lower_semi.svg/1280px-Lower_semi.svg.png)

My interpretation of the limit inf would be something like this

$$\lim_{x \to x_0} \inf f(x) = \lim_{n \to x_0} \inf_{x \geq n} f(x).$$

So for the example at hand ([1](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b0/Lower_semi.svg/1280px-Lower_semi.svg.png)),  $\lim_{x \to x_0} \inf f(x) = -\infty$. I don't see how the lim inf is greater than $f(x_0)$.

Have I misunderstood the definition of lim inf and could someone please point me in the right direction? I would like to be able to understand why the criteria for lower semi-continuity holds.

Comment: $\lim \inf_{x \to x_0} f(x)$ depends only on values of $f$ near $x_0$ and the right side of yuor equation depends on values of $f$ near $\infty$ also.

Comment: Is there a different way to formulate $\lim_{x \to x_0} \inf f(x)$, so that it can be clear that it is not equal to the right hand side?

Comment: I feel like I saw this post yesterday...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [$\liminf$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_inferior_and_limit_superior) and [$\limsup$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_inferior_and_limit_superior) are a local properties of $f$ around $x_0$ which do not depend on the value of $f$ at $x_0$:
$$\lim_{x \to x_0} \inf f(x) = \lim_{r \to 0} \inf_{0<|x-x_0|<r} f(x)$$
and
$$\lim_{x \to x_0} \sup f(x) = \lim_{r \to 0} \sup_{0<|x-x_0|<r} f(x).$$

In your picture, for sufficiently small $r>0$, $\inf_{0<|x-x_0|<r} f(x)=f(x_0-r)$ which tends to $f(x_0)$ as $r\to 0$, and therefore
$$\lim_{x \to x_0} \inf f(x)=\lim_{r\to 0}f(x_0-r)=f(x_0).$$
On the other hand, you can verify that in your picture,
$$\lim_{x \to x_0} \sup f(x)=\lim_{r\to 0}f(x_0+r)>f(x_0).$$

Comment: Are you sure its not $\inf_{0 < |x-x_0| < r} f(x) = f(x_0 + r)$ for a sufficiently small $r$?

Comment: According to your graph, the function you are considering is increasing locally around $x_0$, hence $\inf_{0<|x-x_0|<r} f(x)=f(x_0-r)$

Comment: You're right, I got confused for a second with horizontal function shifting. Thank you for your answer, it cleared things up.

Comment: @ah2kmoada You are welcome!